# bash script is stuck at tee

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, tee

I am using two scripts say `script1` and `script2`. I call `script2` from `script1` which generates lots of text data. I am redirecting this text to a file using tee. But tee is stuck and doesn't move forward.

I cannot give the exact example as scripts are way too long to be included here. So giving a snippet of what's going on.

```
# script1
# Do some task
/bin/bash script2.sh 2>&1 | tee script2.log
capture=$(cat script2.log | grep "Successfully completed" | wc -l)
# Do some more work
```

```
#script2
# Execute some code
# Some python scripts
echo "Script End here"
```

Now when I execute `script1.sh` I am getting `Script End here` indicating second script completed successfully. But script1 is stuck at `tee`. When I removed `tee` and didn't capture output it worked out fine.

Did anyone face this before. Any idea what might be going on.

```
# System details
$ uname -a
Linux jetson-nx-jetpack461 4.9.253-tegra #1 SMP PREEMPT Sat Feb 19 08:58:27 PST 2022 aarch64 aarch64 aarch64 GNU/Linux
```

```
# Bash version
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.4.20(1)-release (aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

From `script2`

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem with the scripts you posted. You need to post something that actually illustrates the problem.

Comment: How do you know `tee` is stuck, maybe the problem is in "# Do some more work"?

Comment: Put `set -x` at the beginning of `script1.sh`, it will show every command as it's executing it.

Comment: FYI you can use `grep -c` instead of piping to `wc -l`.

Comment: My guess would be that script2.sh is doing something like starting a subprocess that persists after script2.sh itself exits, and that's holding the pipe open. But that's just a guess, it's impossible to say without a reproducable example. I'd recommend trying to create a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) by taking a copy of the full script(s), and removing as much as possible, while keeping the problem reproducible (the "divide and conquer" method in the help article I linked).

Comment: @GordonDavisson I think it's likely that `starting a subprocess that persists after script2.sh itself exits` though I checked process exits cleanly. But this might be the reason. Is there any way to forcefully clear all stdout/pipe from `script2.sh` so that we can execute other commands in script1. Though I am trying find a minimal reproduceable example for this.

Comment: @PranjalDoshi I can't think of a way that won't potentially cause different problems. I think you need to isolate what's causing the problem. If it turns out it is a subprocess, you need to decide if its output *should* go through the pipe to `tee`; if not, redirect its output somewhere else (maybe /dev/null); if it should go to `tee`, you may have to rewrite it to close its output when it's done or something like that.

Comment: @GordonDavisson The issue was the script to was executing a `python` script. Which is running `docker run` using `subprocess.run` command. Even though the process exits but it's child process was still running and `tee` was waiting for it's response. This was strange for me because on one machine it was working as expected. Both the system has same `os`, `bash` and `tee` version. The only difference was one system was `arm64` and other was `amd64`. Looks like some issue with python's `subprocess` implementation issue on bot platform.

Answer (score 0):

1. When the script has a large number of lines (1000/2000/...), it is difficult to debug using `set -x`.
2. Either proceed based on comment from Barmar, or you include:

   ```
    echo read1
    read
    command12
    echo read2
    read
    command23
   ```

   View the location where it is hanging.
3. If it is hanging exactly due to tee, use the following command:

   ```
    echo read5
    read
    echo type tee
    type tee
    echo read6
    read
   ```

   Using this we can identify exactly where the script is hanging.
4. You can also use read1.1 read1.0 read1.-1 ... when debugging.